# Different colors of options in selectOneMenu (Primefaces)

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, selectonemenu

I need to display different colors of options in Primefaces.

I have a selectOneMenu with dynamical items (List)

```xml
<p:selectOneMenu id="carMenu" style="margin-top:4px;"
    value="#{Bean.selectedCar}" effect="fade"
    autoupdate="true">
    <f:selectItems id="carsId"
        value="#{myBean.allCars}" var="carItems"
        itemLabel="#{carItems.name}" itemValue="#{carItems}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

```java
 private List<Cars> allCars;
```

If the car is sold, I need to display the background of the option RED otherwise BLACK. In my Model I got an attribute which gives me the value (boolean sold) back if the car is sold or not.

How can I set the colors in my selectOneMenu?

Comment: Thanx, delete my comment. You can delete yoursto to keep everything clean

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The solution is to use the 'advanced' way of displaying this in PrimeFaces 4.0 and newer.

You can combine `f:selectItems` tag with `p:column` tags for `p:selectOneMenu` (see [the showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/oneMenu.xhtml)), with an iteration `var` for the columns themselves, like you do in tables.

Then the ideal thing would be to set the `styleClass` to the entire column depending on the condition, but unfortunatelly it doesn't work. Luckily, adding some Javascript/jQuery code you can achieve your goal, check out this [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/):

**XHTML Page**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" style="height: 400px;">
<h:head>
    <style type="text/css">
red-background {
    //Empty, used just as a reference to set the style with jQuery
}
</style>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form>
        <p:commandButton action="#{bean.send}" value="Send" ajax="false" />
        <p:selectOneMenu id="carMenu" style="margin-top:4px;"
            value="#{bean.selectedCar}" effect="fade" autoupdate="true" var="car"
            converter="omnifaces.SelectItemsConverter" onchange="setSelectionColor();">
            <f:selectItems id="carsId" value="#{bean.allCars}" var="carItem"
                itemLabel="#{carItem.name}" itemValue="#{carItem}" />
            <p:column>
                <h:outputText value="#{car.name}"
                    styleClass="#{car.sold ? 'red-background' : ''}" />
            </p:column>
        </p:selectOneMenu>
    </h:form>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            //Set red background for the options (not for td, but for its parent tr)
            $(".red-background").parent().css( "background-color", "red" );
            setSelectionColor();
        });
        function setSelectionColor(){
            //Check if the selected value has a red background 
            //(active and red-background styles altogether), 
            //if true, set the selectonemenu label to red too
            if($(".ui-state-active .red-background").size() > 0){
                $(".ui-selectonemenu-label").css( "background-color", "red" );
            }else{
                $(".ui-selectonemenu-label").css( "background-color", "white" );
            }
        }
    </script>
</h:body>
</html>
```

**Bean.java**

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class Bean implements Serializable {

    public class Car implements Serializable {
        String name;
        boolean sold;

        public Car(String name, boolean sold) {
            this.name = name;
            this.sold = sold;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public boolean isSold() {
            return sold;
        }
    }

    private List<Car> allCars = Arrays.asList(new Car("Audi", true), new Car(
            "Mercedes", false));

    public List<Car> getAllCars() {
        return allCars;
    }

    private Car selectedCar;

    public Car getSelectedCar() {
        return selectedCar;
    }

    public void setSelectedCar(Car selectedCar) {
        this.selectedCar = selectedCar;
    }

    public void send() {
        System.out.println("Sent " + selectedCar.name);
    }

}
```

You might also be interested in setting only the font color and not the background:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>
    <style type="text/css">
.red-font {
    color: red;
}
</style>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form>
        <p:commandButton action="#{bean.send}" value="Send" ajax="false" />
        <p:selectOneMenu id="carMenu" style="margin-top:4px;"
            value="#{bean.selectedCar}" effect="fade" autoupdate="true"
            var="car"
            converter="omnifaces.SelectItemsConverter">
            <f:selectItems id="carsId" value="#{bean.allCars}" var="carItems"
                itemLabel="#{carItems.name}" itemValue="#{carItems}" />
            <p:column>
                <h:outputText styleClass="#{car.sold ? 'red-font' : ''}"
                    value="#{car.name}" />
            </p:column>
        </p:selectOneMenu>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```