# How to set colour to f:selectItem in primefaces?

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces

How to set colour for selectOneMenu in primefaces ?

```
 <p:selectOneMenu id="col" value="#{projectsController.selected.listColor}">
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Activity" itemValue="1"  class="redBackGroundColor"/>
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Activity1" itemValue="2" class="blueBackGroundColor"/>
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Activity2" itemValue="3" class="greenBackGroundColor"/>

                </p:selectOneMenu>
```

And here is my css

```
.redBackGroundColor{
    background-color:red;        
}
```

(and ofcourse for blue and green..)
But it doesnt affect behavior of primeface.

Comment: It seems there is a workaround in PrimeFaces 4.0. Maybe this is still valid: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19403631/different-colors-of-options-in-selectonemenu-primefaces

Comment: It's not a workaround but the PrimeFaces advanced way of displaying this and still valid. See http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/oneMenu.xhtml

Answer (score 0):

it's impossible in JSP
but you can do that in javascript

for example :

```
      $(this).children("tbody").children("tr").each(function () {
              if ($(this).children("td").children("input").val() == 1) {
                       $(this).addClass("redBackGroundColor");
                }
```

.....
   It's work for me.

Comment: Imo this, is a bad complex workaround compared to the 'advanced' display of selectItems in selectOneMenu