# Display some of the items striked in primefaces multiselect checkbox dropdown

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2

I am working on primefaces application, where I have to implement a functionality to display list of user objects in dropdown and user can select multiple user objects and filter it.

If the user is deleted or inactive I need to display that user value in striked out.

I seen this link and implemented same way but nothing worked

[Different colors of options in selectOneMenu (Primefaces)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19403631/different-colors-of-options-in-selectonemenu-primefaces)

If I used this below selectManyMenu, dropdown is coming in page load itself, but the dropdown should come when the user selects the dropdown

https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/manyMenu.xhtml

As this functionality exist in many places I wrote a custom dropdown:

```
<cc:interface>
    <cc:attribute name="id" required="true"/>       
    <cc:attribute name="value" required="true"/>
    <cc:attribute name="converterId"  type="java.lang.String"/>
</cc:interface>

<cc:implementation>
    <div class="userCheckBoxMenu">
        <div style="display: inline-block; position: relative;">
            <p:selectCheckboxMenu
                  var="t" filter="true" filterMatchMode="contains" showCheckbox="true">
                        <f:selectItems value="${cc.attrs.value}" var="u" itemLabel="#{myBean.formatUser(u)}" itemValue="#{u}"/>
                        <p:column>
                            <h:outputText value="#{myBean.formatUser(t)}" styleClass="#{myBean.isValidUser(t)} ? 'white-background' :'invalid-user-text'" />
                        </p:column>
                        <f:converter converterId="converterId" />

            </p:selectCheckboxMenu>

        </div>
    </div>
</cc:implementation>
```

Dropdown is coming but invalid user value still showing normally, not striked out.

When I see the generated html, for `p:selectOneMenu` it's generating `table` for the dropdown, but for `p:selectCheckBoxMenu` it's generating `div` element, and the column is generating another dropdown but it's hidden.

Confused about it, how to handle this situation?

Thanks in advance!!!!!!!

Comment: What if you remove the  `p:colum`? Does it display the same then?

Comment: Yes, even after removing `p:column` , showing the same  @Kukeltje

Comment: So the `p:colum` does not do anything... I nowhere in the docs and showcase see that a `p:column` is supported