# p:datatable - row editing - cell menu items not visible when selecting row to edit

Tags: jsf, primefaces, roweditor

I am new to JSF. I have a `p:datatable` in which I set to edit rows, but just editing one of the cells. I have the row selection icon, the one looking like a pencil, and then the icons for confirming the editing and for cancelling the editing. When I select the row to edit, the menu of the involved cell does not show the item values (in my case booleans - true/false). Even if, when I put the mouse over an item, this shows.

I don't get any warning/error/exception with that.

[image: my cell menu image]

```
<p:column headerText="Available">
    <p:cellEditor>
        <f:facet name="output">
            <h:outputText value="#{device.available}" />
        </f:facet>
        <f:facet name="input">
            <h:selectOneMenu value="#{device.available}" style="width:100%">
                <f:selectItems value="#{dtDeviceView.availableValues}" var="bool_value" itemLabel="#{bool_value}" itemValue="#{bool_value}" />
            </h:selectOneMenu>
        </f:facet>
    </p:cellEditor>
</p:column>
```

I'm Using JSF 2.2 (Mojarra 2.3.5) And PrimeFaces 6.2.

How can I solve it?

[**SOLVED**]
I just needed

```
<style type="text/css">
    .black-font {
        color: black;
    }
</style>
```

in the head of my xhtml file and `styleClass="#{'black-font'}"` in my `h:selectOneMenu` tag:

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{device.available}" style="width:100%" styleClass="#{'black-font'}">
```

Comment: Hi, I improved your question a little. Can you fill out the bold additions? And please create an [mcve] like requested in [ask] and https://www.stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info

Comment: Did you check the source? By accident white on white?

Comment: I don't have any reference to colours in the code! :)

Comment: You don't but CSS has

Comment: So, since i haven't used CSS (I don't even know CSS), how can I proceed? :)

Comment: By learning basics of css, basics of webdevelopment and the usage of a browser developer tool

Comment: Solved. This has helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19403631/different-colors-of-options-in-selectonemenu-primefaces (in a piece of code about FONT colour).